# Cycles, get object passes through glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

How can I get any render passes of the monkey object which is placed into glass sphere.

pic.1 - combined view
[image]

pic.2 - IndexObj
[image]

pic.3 - IndexMA
[image]

pic.4 - AOV Output - color
[image]

pic.5 - AOV Output - value
[image]

pic.6 - Cryptomate - assets
[image]

pic.7 - Cryptomate - material
[image]

pic.8 - Cryptomate - objects
[image]

Comment: I believe that's currently not possible with Cryptomatte or Object ID passes since they don't support refraction or reflection.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104367/29586