# Compositing : change color behind glass

Tags: compositing-nodes

I modeling a watch and want to use the compositor to change the lume color.
But, in the compositor, I can't access anything under the glass so I can't change to color on the hands.

The only way I can do it is using a transparent shader instead of a glass shader (but in that case, I loosing the refraction and i really want to keep it...)

Does anyone have a hint to do it ?

[image: Composite pass]

[image: compositing and changing lume]

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104367/29586

Comment: Thanks, I just looked at it and add a emission shader to the torus in the example.
Unfortunalty, it seems the "emit" channel behind the glass doesn't show up even in the "visible layer". So I can't use a mask to play with it :(

Comment: You don't actually use the 'emit' channel in that solution. Instead, it's a whole new render layer just rendering that emission and how it's contributing to the final image. You can then combine that 'mask' layer with the original render and use that to manipulate the result without having to re-render. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense.
I would have love to only change the emission color and keep the base color. But this solution is way better thant nothing !